# Deleting topic caused errors when consuming multiple kafka topic by a regex pattern

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

Recently we are doing some streaming jobs with apache flink. There are multiple KAFKA topics with a format as xxxxxx_yy-mm-dd. We used a topic regex pattern to let a consumer to consume those topics. However, if we delete some older topics, it seems that the metadata in consumer does not update properly. It still remember those outdated topic in its topic list? so the **UNKNOWN_TOPIC_EXCEPTIOIN**. We must restart the consumer job to recovery. It seems to occur in producer as well. Any idea to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: What version of Kafka are you running on the flink application side? Do the exceptions persist until restart or do they happen once? Do you find all consumption stops or just that the exceptions are logged?

Comment: What is your programming language?

Comment: 1. versions: Kafka011    2. exception keep occurs until I restart the job.   3.the consumption will be stopped.

Comment: This sounds like a bug, and I don't see that this has been reported before. Can you create a ticket in JIRA? https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/FLINK

Comment: I have opened a issue in JIRA , https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11848?filter=-2